# What's the usual folder where the Dart Editor and SDK (after unzipped the download) are installed/moved to?

Tags: macos, dart

What's the usual folder where the Dart Editor and SDK (after unzipped the download) are installed/moved to? (`/Applications`)?

Comment: There is homebrew support, wouldn't it be easier to use this?http://news.dartlang.org/2014/10/dart-launches-support-for-homebrew.html?m=1 I'm no Mac user and don't have used it myself.

Answer (score 26):

Please follow the https://dart.dev/get-dart

```
$ brew tap dart-lang/dart
$ brew install dart
```

and then:

```
$ brew info dart
```

And you will see:
`/usr/local/opt/dart/libexec`

Answer (score 16):

```
Please note the path to the Dart SDK:
/usr/local/opt/dart/libexec

--with-dartium:
To use with IntelliJ, set the Dartium execute home to:
/usr/local/opt/dart/Chromium.app
```

Other information: https://www.dartlang.org/downloads/mac.html

Answer (score 8):

refer to https://dart.dev/get-dart

```
$ brew tap dart-lang/dart
$ brew install dart
```

once installation completes , then

```
$ brew info dart
```

which gives result

```
brew info dart
dart-lang/dart/dart: stable 2.7.0, devel 2.8.0-dev.2.0
The Dart SDK
https://www.dartlang.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.7.0 (474 files, 463.4MB) *
  Built from source on 2020-01-15 at 16:53:13
From: https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/blob/master/dart.rb
==> Options
--devel
    Install development version 2.8.0-dev.2.0
==> Caveats
Please note the path to the Dart SDK:
  /usr/local/opt/dart/libexec
```

Answer (score 4):

I advise to you install Dart through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Homebrew is a very well crafted piece of software and you can use it to install a lot of things that you might need now or in the future. And it's simple to use; to install dart, all you have to do is

```
brew tap dart-lang/dart
brew install dart
```

Note that usually you only have to do the `brew install X` part, but Dart is a [special case](https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart).

Comment: Ok thanks. Does this install the complete package (= same as the Dart Editor + SDK download) or only the SDK?

Comment: This only installs the SDK and, depending on the flags you pass to Homebrew, the Dartium browser. If you want the Dart Editor, you can either get it through [Caskroom](http://caskroom.io/) via  `brew cask install darteditor` or from the [Dart website](https://www.dartlang.org/downloads/). *Caveat emptor*: The Dart Editor is [no longer](http://news.dartlang.org/2015/04/the-present-and-future-of-editors-and.html) under active development.

Answer (score 3):

If you've used `brew` to install `flutter` then Dart's SDK can be found under:

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/<version>/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk
```

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411384/2016436