# Where is Dart's SDK located within /flutter folder?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

### Software

```
MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
Android Studio 3.1.2
Flutter 0.3.2 • channel beta
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.48.0.flutter-fe606f890b
Flutter doctor (no problems found)
```

### Problem

Dart's SDK is supposed to be bundled when Flutter is downloaded according to the documentation:

> ["The Dart SDK is bundled with Flutter; it is not necessary to install Dart separately"](https://flutter.io/setup-macos/)

However, I opened an existing Flutter project with Android Studio and it suggested me to either "**Download Dart SDK**" or "**Open Dart settings**":

[image: Image of Android Studio suggesting to "download Dart SDK"]

Apparently, I need to "**Open Dart settings**" and tell Android Studio where to find the Dart' SDK. However, it can't find it within the `flutter/` directory.

Comment: The Dart SDK bundled with flutter is located in the folder `flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin`.  However, if you have the Flutter plugin installed and are in a Flutter project you should not need to configure this.

Comment: The plugin was already installed https://i.imgur.com/ggToUXX.png

Comment: Thanks, I updated the flutter SDK path and it's working now.

Comment: Yesterday in first time installed dart via brew, try to find dart sdk via IntelligeIDE but didnt found...

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The **Dart's SDK** is located at `/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`

However, If Android Studio's **flutter plugin** is installed, the plugin needs to be told where **flutter's SDK** is located. Android Studio should be able to locate **Dart's SDK** afterwards:

[image]

Comment: I have flutter-sdk and flutter plugin installed, yet when I imported a dart library project, I still had to point idea to dart sdk folder just like the author of the original question...

Comment: What @morgwai has replied is right, we still need path and Thats "/bin/cache/dart-sdk" Abu Yosuf replied

Answer (score 203):

The Dart SDK lives inside the `bin/cache/dart-sdk` folder of the Flutter SDK. It will be downloaded the first time you run the `flutter` command, so may not exist if you've not yet run `flutter`.

Comment: So I must manually add a specific path to `dart-sdk` to `.zshrc` file?

Comment: @Anatoly generally, no - you should not add that path to your PATH explicitly. Generally you will use the `flutter` command so you shouldn't need this on `PATH`. Upcoming versions of Flutter will include a `dart` binary in the normal `bin` folder so that you can use `dart` from the command line easily.

Comment: Hi there ! If I just happened to want to call the dart sdk, I could add bin/cache/dart-sdk to .zshrc file?

Comment: update, yes you can manually add a path to the dart-sdk in flutter and get access to dart from the command line !

Comment: export PATH="$PATH:/Users/gene/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk"

Comment: Linux, snap install: `$HOME/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`

Answer (score 13):

If someone is looking for the path to flutter sdk in Linux I found mine here

`/home/your_username/flutter/common/flutter/` flutter path
`/home/your_username/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk` dart path

Answer (score 12):

I have downloaded flutter sdk via `homebrew`

For Mac OS: 10.14.5

Android Studio version : Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Flutter sdk location is `/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.0/flutter`

Dart location: `/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.0/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`

Answer (score 10):

After installing flutter however you choose.

1. run the following command

> flutter sdk-path

2. In Android-Studio select File->Setting->Languages & Frameworks->Flutter
   (assuming you have installed teh flutter plugin)
3. Populate the "Flutter SDK path:" with the result from (1).
4. Click apply. The Dart SDK should automatically get populated.

For my installation the values are:

> Flutter SDK path: /home/andrew/snap/flutter/common/flutter

> Dart SDK path: /home/andrew/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk

Comment: _“Could not find a command named "sdk-path".”_ –

Comment: no such command as "flutter sdk-path", command doesn't appear to exist

Comment: best answer by far as others have left out absolute path.  this works on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 5):

Run `brew info flutter`

Then you get the path: e.g.
`/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3`

And there the `bin/cache` has the dartk-sdk:

`/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`

Comment: Thanks "flutter/bin/cache" is the path

Answer (score 4):

Check this:

`brew info dart`

Output:

`Please note the path to the Dart SDK:  /opt/homebrew/opt/dart/libexec`

Answer (score 3):

You can choose on of dart or flutter path, because flutter package include dart sdk.
Or you could install dart standalone.

### From "dart"

##### (Windows)

> `choco install dart-sdk` (ensure Dart installed)

Dart SDK path is: `C:\tools\dart-sdk`

##### (macOS)

> `brew install dart` (ensure Dart installed)
> `brew info dart`

Dart SDK path is: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/x.x.x/libexec`

### From "flutter"

##### (Windows)

> (ensure flutter installed and $PATH configured)
>
> `where flutter`
> and you will get `{path_to_directory}\flutter\bin\flutter`

Dart SDK path is:
`{path_to_directory}\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk`

Flutter SDK path is:
`{path_to_directory}\flutter`

##### (macOS)

> (ensure flutter installed and $PATH configured)
>
> `brew info flutter`

Dart SDK path is:
`/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/x.xx.x/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`

Flutter SDK path is:
`/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/x.xx.x/flutter`

---

#### For those who want to create a new Dart Project:

[image: create Dart project]

#### For those who want to create a new Flutter Project:

[image: create Flutter project - dart sdk]

[image: create Flutter project - flutter sdk]

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Dart on Windows via Chocolatey, you will find it on `C:\tools\dart-sdk`

Answer (score 1):

If **Android Studio** show - `Error: Dart SDK is not configured`.
Open Linux console and write: `flutter sdk-path`. Copy output.
Next `Settings` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) => `Languages & Frameworks` => `Flutter` => `Flutter SDK path`.
Paste SDK path.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue,

1. Go to the folder where you have downloaded flutter and then delete the flutter folder.
2. Go to your download folder and where you have downloaded the flutter the first time.
3. Extract this file again where you have deleted the flutter...

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is the `build` directory that he cannot create, suddenly devtools crashes, you can simply recreate it in `$HOME/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/devtools-your-version`, then give it the right rights with for example `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/devtools-your-version/build` after re-creating the build directory

Answer (score -1):

Everyone that is still searching for the correct answer should checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63409260/9823820.

If you have the flutter SDK installed.

Run:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

The first line will show the install path.

Credits go to [@Lee Higgins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6205147/lee-higgins)