# Flutter, where is the Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

So, I've downloaded flutter SDK `1.17.5-stable` and installed it following the [manual](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) but I confused a little bit by tutorial.

According to manual:

> As of Flutter’s 1.19.0 dev release, the Flutter SDK contains the dart command alongside the flutter command so that you can more easily run Dart command-line programs.

But `flutter/bin` has only a single binary, `flutter` itself. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411384/947111) I found `dart` binary located within `bin/cache/dart-sdk`.

I definitely can add path to this directory to my `.zshrc` and it will work, but I would like to know if it intended behavior and manual just not updated and I haven't done anything wrong.

Comment: It is intended.

Comment: If it mentioned in official docs, can you point me there?

Comment: And I understand that I need to add full path to `dart-sdk` at `.zshrc`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved! I didn't pay attention that `1.17.5` < `1.19.0` and `1.19.0` still in [beta/dev channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos) as of date 15/Jul/2020, so tutorial was updated for release which hasn't been released yet.