# Error: Dart SDK is not found in the specified location

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a new project on IntelliJ but I get the "Error: Dart SDK is not found in the specified location ".  I think I have the correct pathway? It even shows the version I have. But it doesn't recognize it I think.

I got that pathway from the  "flutter doctor -v" command

IMAGES:

IntelliJ => https://prnt.sc/iuJrIlFOsLSn

CMD      => https://prnt.sc/gebEZmwnWMdp

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321966/where-is-darts-sdk-located-within-flutter-folder

Answer (score 1):

Try choosing the `path\to\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk` path instead